# Recognised image will return a text

Tags: android, text, replace, vuforia

I use Qualcomm Vuforia's ImageTarget sample. I managed to use my own image instead of sample images to get 'tea pot model' but i want to see a writing.   Simply, question is, How can i replace 'Tea Pot model' with a 'text'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the openGL scene (renderFrameQCAR method) in order to display a text (you can use GLFont tool).